# Angular2 Conditional Router and Injecting the current Router instance

Tags: angular, components, angular-routing

I have this subcomponent (And router outlet) which works okey-dokey for me.

However I want the landing page to be conditional on the user's Role.
In this particular case it's a User Component, Normal users should see their personal page, admins should see a list of all users.

I can't seem to set up a conditional landing page, so Right now I made a Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-component',
  template: '<router-outlet name="user"></router-outlet>',
  directives: [MdButton, AuthRouterOutlet],
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/detail/',     component: UserDetail,    name: 'Detail',       data: {role: UserRole.USER } },
  { path: '/overview',    component: UserOverview,  name: 'Overview',     data: {role: UserRole.USER} },
  { path: '/detail/:id',  component: UserDetail,    name: 'AdminDetail',  data: {role: UserRole.ADMIN } },
  { path: '/add',         component: UserForm,      name: 'Add',          data: {role: UserRole.ADMIN } },
  { path: '/edit/:id',    component: UserForm,      name: 'Edit',         data: {role: UserRole.ADMIN} },
  { path: '/landing',     component: Landing,       name: 'Landing',      data: {role: null}, useAsDefault: true }
])
export class UserComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

@Component({selector: 'landing-none', template: '<div></div>'})
export class Landing {
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, router: Router) {
    if (sessionService.isAdmin()) {
      router.navigate(['Overview']);
    } else if (sessionService.isAuthenticated()) {
      router.navigate(['Detail']);
    } else {
      router.navigateByUrl('');
    }
  }
}
```

The data property is being used in the custom AuthRouterAutlet, It's being checked against the sessionService just like in the Landing component.

In this case however I cannot inject the router property, it keeps complaining that the routes are incorrect, well yes I didn't define any since I want the provider from my UserComponent.

Anyone have any thoughts on this case? Am I doing something silly?

Comment: Do you have landing component in same file? If yes, move it to other file?

Comment: Could you maybe add this as answer and tell me why it works this way?
I mean I got it to work but I want to understand why.